# Mysql insert command to have verbose

Tags: mysql, linux

I need some assistance with find a way for the following command to verbose the commands that are running:

```
cat /tmp/queuemetrics_queue_log.sql |mysql queuemetrics
```

Regards

Comment: Use the `-v` option to `mysql`?

Comment: Thanks seams to be working, atleast I can see the information being processed.

Answer (score 0):

To see which statements are being processed you can run the command with the -v flag:

```
$ mysql -v -e 'select database(); show variables like "a%" '
--------------
select database()
--------------

+------------+
| database() |
+------------+
| foobarz    |
+------------+
--------------
show variables like "a%"
--------------

+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name               | Value                         |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| activate_all_roles_on_login | OFF                           |
| admin_address               |                               |
| admin_port                  | 33062                         |
| admin_ssl_ca                |                               |
| admin_ssl_capath            |                               |
| admin_ssl_cert              |                               |
| admin_ssl_cipher            |                               |
| admin_ssl_crl               |                               |
| admin_ssl_crlpath           |                               |
| admin_ssl_key               |                               |
| admin_tls_ciphersuites      |                               |
| admin_tls_version           | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| auto_generate_certs         | ON                            |
| auto_increment_increment    | 1                             |
| auto_increment_offset       | 1                             |
| autocommit                  | ON                            |
| automatic_sp_privileges     | ON                            |
| avoid_temporal_upgrade      | OFF                           |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
```